# Step into/debug WCF service which is in a different solution from the client

Tags: c#, wcf, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I have a client application, and in a different solution, I have a WCF service which this client uses. I want to be able to step into the WCF service when the client calls a WCF method. I had tried debugging both of them, that didn't work. Then I tried debugging the client, and debugging the service by attaching it to the client Visual Studio's 'devenv.exe' process(had read this somewhere in an SO answer). Both didn't work.
Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Use Fiddler to debug WCF services, here is the link http://www.telerik.com/fiddler. Here is an example on how to debug your wcf service with fiddler: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/213007/Debug-WCF-REST-Service

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to do this. Update the service reference in the client after you start the WCF service in debug mode. You can always keep the break point in the WCF service and it should hit whenever the function is called

Answer (score 0):

When you say you tried debugging both of them, where exactly did this not work? After you run the WCF service locally (remember to build debug), refresh the service reference on the client, you should be able to insert breakpoints in both and it should work. Are you using one or multiple instances of VS ?

I have debugged multiple WCF services by running multiple instances of Visual Studio (one per client & one per wcf service instance) and then simply inserting break points in both. When the client calls the service call, it will break at the breakpoint.

Did I, perhaps, misunderstand what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

1. create or load your Web Service application in a separate solution
   than your client and host it on localhost
2. Set your breakpoint and start the debug process - This should open up the Web Service default page in a browser
3. Load the client solution in a separate solution and set a go to the breakpoint in your client application and step into (F11)
4. This should toggle to the web method in your web service

Note: Make sure you are pointing to the correct port and your localhost either from the code or your app.config file, i.e.:

add key="PLWSURL" value="http://localhost:2020/yourwebservice.asmx